# add bootstrap in wordpress file

Tags: php, wordpress

I was developing a custom form page for the first time. it is on taking review from the customers . I am using the Astra theme.

Bootstrap is not working, and the style function is not functional. When opened on the wordpress local site, everything (form, heading, and even hr tag) appears on the left side.

```
 <?php
 /* Template Name: Custom Review Page */
 get_header(); // Include header
 ?>

<div id="content">
  <?php
   function enqueue_bootstrap() {
    // Enqueue jQuery first
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // Enqueue Bootstrap CSS
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

    // Enqueue Bootstrap JavaScript
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '4.0.0', true);
     }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_bootstrap');    

?>
 <div style="text-align: center;">
<h2>Add A Review</h2>
<hr style="border: 0; height: 1px; background: #000; margin: 0 auto;">
 </div>
<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">

 <form method="POST">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <label>Full name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <label>Country</label>
        <input type="text" name="Country" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <label>Rating</label>
        <input type="text" name="Rating" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-12">
    <label>Your message</label>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-12">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</div>
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>


 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['fullname']);
    $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
    $country = sanitize_text_field($_POST['Country']);
    $rating = intval($_POST['Rating']); // Assuming it's an integer.
    $message = sanitize_text_field($_POST['message']);

    global $wpbd;

   // $sql=$wpdb->insert("tablename",array())
    $sql=$wpdb->insert("review_form",array("fullname"=>$name,"email"=>$email,"country"=>$country,"rating"=>$rating,"message"=>$message));

    if($sql==true){
    echo "<script> alert('data inserted') </script>";
    }
    else{
    echo "<script> alert('data not inserted') </script>";
    }
    


}
else{ 
}
?>
</div>

<?php
get_footer(); // Include footer
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mihir!
Firstly, Configure The Bootstrap Library Correctly with Wordpress
So, Go On This Location: `Apperance < Theme File Editor < Header.php`

And Add The Bootstrap Files Link In `Header.php`

Which Are: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
And `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">`

After, Add These Links In Header.php You Are Able To Use Sections Of Bootstrap

Comment: but adding script is not helping it

Answer (score 0):

1. Open theme's functions.php file
2. In your child theme's functions.php file, enqueue the Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript files. You can do this by adding the following code
3. 

```php
function enqueue_bootstrap() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_bootstrap');
```